# Perl CGI vs C CGI in mod_perl WebServer

Tags: c++, perl, cgi, fastcgi, mod-perl

Im thinking in refactor my application migrating my Perl CGI to a C++ CGI.

I'm trying to improve performance, because we need more runtime speed procesing.

Taking into account that mod_perl compile once at startup the Perl CGI:

Is it possible getting better performance using a C/C++ CGI? (in this case over FastCGI)

It have sense?

Answer (score 4):

If you want calculate the `PI` in your C/CGI script to several thousand places, probably yes, because of calculation speed of compiled probram is much faster.

But, If your C/CGI will output only "hello world" probably not. :)

Result: impossible to say without some benchmarks and indepth analysis what causes the slowness.

What you should do? Only IMHO :)

- replace apache with `nginx`
- replace your plain CGI with PGSI based perl apllication. (if you want refactor to C you can easier refactor to Plack/PSGI
- use some small framework to get fast results
- run the final Plack APP as standalone perl/web server behing the `nginx` reverse proxy
- configure `nginx` to serve static files

done ;)

You can test Plack/PSGI solution in 5 min - using the [Plack::Handler::CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Handler::CGI) or with [CGI::Emulate::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Emulate::PSGI)

Again, all above is only IMHO, as you know - maybe your mileage is ... ;)

Comment: @moalaiskirulais while i'm happy with the accept, you should wait a bit longer, maybe someone other will give a better answer ;) :)